# Why are there parentheses around the value for count in this snippet?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is a snippet of a React component.

```
    state = {
        count: 0
    };

    increment = () => {
        this.setState({
                count: (this.state.count + 1)
        });
    };

    decrement = () => {
        this.setState({
            count: (this.state.count - 1)
        })
    }
```

However, I am trying to understand why there are parentheses around the value for `count: (this.state.count + 1)`. Why couldn't we just have `count: this.state.count + 1`?

Just in case you are interested in knowing the source, I was looking at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-typescript-with-react.

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: In this case parentheses just make code easier to read

Comment: I see. Thank you to the both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the answer is that the parentheses are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

By the way you should do that this way for better synchronization between react updates:

```
increment = () => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
                count: prevState.count + 1
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for that insight.